# Unity AR causes lag on the whole game

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm developing a game which has several minigames, one of them is a AR game, it works as expected but when I close the AR minigame (load other games scenes) , All games run with lag(like 20 fps or even less) which only happens after loading the AR minigame, before loading AR they run smoothly.
Should I disable the AR somehow before changing the scene? Is there a way to avoid the lag? thank you

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to close the AR minigame?

Comment: I just load another scene , SceneManager.LoadScene("...")

Comment: Have you tried `SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("...")` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync.html

Comment: Just tried it, Unfortunately doesn't make any difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I realized that the problem is that AR limits the FPS to 30  So I solved it by setting the target fps to 60 again and disabling vsync(Idk if that is necessary):

```
QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
```